# 3 prisoner problem slightly reworded. Who is right?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Three prisoners, A, B and C, have been told by their jailer that one of them, chosen
at random, will be executed, and the other two will be freed. Prisoner A says to the
jailer,“I know that one of the other prisoners must be freed, so why don’t you tell me
which of the two it will be, or tell me one name at random if they are both to be freed?
It can’t change my chances of being executed.” The jailer replies, “Once I’ve told you
a name, that only leaves two people, so your chances of being executed will have gone
up to 1 in 2.” Who is right?

Let A = Event that A is executed.
Let B and C = " ".

I am now confused about whether I have to define one single event that A is told, or do I define three separate ones, i.e. A is told it will B, A is told it will be C, A is told it will be A (obviously with probability 0).

Comment: This is the usual Monty Hall problem.  Prisoner $A$'s perceived probabilty that they are the unlucky party is unchanged.  Of course, the unselected other prisoner has seen their probability increase to $\frac 23$ (the fact that the warden avoided naming them, either by intent or by hazard, is evidence of their unlucky status).

Comment: This makes sense to me, it's just I'm not entirely sure how to actually prove it using Bayes' theorem

Comment: Look up the usual proofs of the Monty Hall problem.